# Flutter and Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've set up firebase with Flutter for iOS and Android.
When running `flutter run` I'm getting the error with the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()
(app/no-app).
    at Object.f [as app] (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js:1:17054)
    at Object.app$ [as app]
    (http://localhost:50861/packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart.lib.js:42:101)
    at initializeApp
    (http://localhost:50861/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:101:25)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39052:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39083:7)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp
    (http://localhost:50861/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:94:20)
    at initializeApp (http://localhost:50861/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:117:59)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39052:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39083:7)
    at Function.initializeApp
    (http://localhost:50861/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:116:20)
    at main$ (http://localhost:50861/packages/scbeta/main.dart.lib.js:477:36)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39052:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39083:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:50861/packages/scbeta/main.dart.lib.js:475:18)
    at main (http://localhost:50861/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:49:29)
    at main.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39032:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:38889:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:33875:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34435:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34473:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34315:23)
    at http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:33526:46
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:38889:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:33875:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34435:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34473:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34315:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34338:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39176:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:39182:13)
    at http://localhost:50861/dart_sdk.js:34689:9
```

The main function in my `main.dart` looks like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I haven't made any firebase calls or initialisations anywhere else in the app.
In my `pubspec.yaml` I only have `firebase_core: ^1.0.1` as a dependency

I have looked at several questions on StackOverflow of people who've had similar problems but none of the solutions where of any help to me.

Comment: Execute flutter clean

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.
The problem was, that with Flutter 2 which just came out a few days ago, you have to add web as a platform as well which none of the tutorials or solutions I've seen mentioned. Once I've added Web on firebase and the scripts in flutter it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created firebase app and configure it for your flutter app?

Comment: hmm. try to comment the firebase_core: ^1.0.1 to determine if it's the cause of the error.

Comment: When I comment that, I have to comment the stuff in the main.dart as well because it needs the Firebase Core dependency for the import but when I comment all the firebase stuff in the main and pub spec then the app runs so it's an issue with firebase and not flutter.

Comment: if that's the case, I suggest you to follow this instruction step by step https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase#0 this helps me a lot setting up firebase with my flutter app.

Comment: I'll set up a new project and see if I have the same problem again